# can you specify a method in another code file using xlcOnKey and ExcelDNA

Tags: c#, excel-dna

I can successfully register a method to a excel keystroke within the same code file / namespace and like this:

```
XlCall.Excel(XlCall.xlcOnKey, "^t", "TESTMETHOD");
```

can I somehow specify a method in a different static class in another file? Eg:

```
XlCall.Excel(XlCall.xlcOnKey, "c", "utilClass.TESTMETHOD");
```

When I try this Excel tells me "Cannot run the macro utilClass.TESTMETHOD. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can. The name of the class is not relevant when using Excel-DNA's default registration mechanism (which seems to be your case).

By default, Excel-DNA scans your add-in assembly for static methods in public classes and automatically registers them as *commands* or *functions* **with the same name as the method name *without* considering the name of the class the method belongs to**.

That means that when you move `TESTMETHOD` to a class called `utilClass`, it will still be registered with Excel as `TESTMETHOD`, therefore, your registration code remains the same, even with the method being on a different class:

```
XlCall.Excel(XlCall.xlcOnKey, "^t", "TESTMETHOD");
```

If you want to define a custom name for your command, you can use add the `ExcelCommand` attribute and set the name you want (example below) or alternatively you can use the [Excel-DNA Custom Registration library](https://github.com/Excel-DNA/Registration) if you want to have more control over the registration.

```
public static class UtilClass
{
    [ExcelCommand(Name = "UtilClass.TestMethod")]
    public static void TestMethod()
    {
        // ...
    }
}

public class MyAddIn : IExcelAddIn
{
    public void AutoOpen()
    {
        XlCall.Excel(XlCall.xlcOnKey, "^t", "UtilClass.TestMethod");
    }

    // ...
}
```

---

It's worth mentioning that you can easily define the shortcut directly in the `ExcelCommand` attribute without having to call `XlCall.Excel` at all to register the shortcut... E.g.

```
public static class UtilClass
{
    [ExcelCommand(Name = "UtilClass.TestMethod", ShortCut = "^t")]
    public static void TestMethod()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

The above will automatically register a command called `UtilClass.TestMethod` that can be triggered via <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>.